# How to grant other system permission to access to my APIs?

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm figuring out how to grant other system permission to access to my APIs in Nodejs Express. I understand that other system need a key and a secret to access to my APIs but I don't really know what to do with them. Should I save it like username and password or sth? Can someone help me out!

I expect other system can access and use some specific API that I grant them permission.
Thanks a lot!